# take numeric values from text

Tags: sql, ms-access

i have values such as 
    1st
    2nd
    3rd
    4th
how would use an sql statement to just take the numbers and put them in a table so that i just have 1,2,3,4

right now i am trying this code below

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE DEDValidation LEFT JOIN ReqInput ON DEDValidation.[Plan Code] = ReqInput.[Plan Code] SET DEDValidation.[Expected Plan Effective Day] =ReqInput.[Start Day] WHERE DEDValidation.[DED Row Found] = 'Yes'"
DoCmd.RunSQL "Update DEDValidation Set DEDValidation.[Expected Plan Effective Day] = REPLACE(DEDValidation.[Expected Plan Effective Day], '*st', '') WHERE DEDValidation.[Expected Plan Effective Day] LIKE '*st'"
```

the first line imports the code and the second is supposed to replace the letters 'st' with a blank, but its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Change the Replace function for this:

```
REPLACE(DEDValidation.[Expected Plan Effective Day], 'st', '')
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: What about "nd" and "rd" and "th"?

Comment: He ask about the "st". He could run several query for update every combination ("rd" and "nd"). Not ideal but the real problem here is the original data.

Comment: i was just trying to make it work for one, after that is really easy, so now im just going to nest the other replaces, 
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(DEDValidation.[Expected Plan Effective Day], 'st', ''),'nd', ''),'rd', ''),'th', '')

Comment: Replace(expectedplaneffectiveday,'[A-Z]','') may be a bit nicer to read.